# R: a False or NA that returns False

Tags: r, logical-operators, na

In the R language, I need an operator that returns a | b, except if either a or b is NA and the other one is F.

Currently, F | NA returns NA, I would like it to return F.

This function should work with vectors.

Any idea?

Comment: what about `TRUE | NA` ? `NA | NA` ?

Comment: @Cath, currently, T | NA returns NA and NA | NA returns NA. This behavior should be preserved.

Comment: With my R version (3.3.0) `TRUE | NA` returns `TRUE`....

Comment: my mistake in the comment above. As I said at the beginning, this function should return the same as the "or" function |, except for when F|NA.

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

```
myor = function(a,b){
  !((is.na(a) & !b) | (is.na(b) & !a) | (!a & !b))
}   

> myor(T,T)
[1] TRUE
> myor(T,F)
[1] TRUE
> myor(F,F)
[1] FALSE
> myor(F,NA)
[1] FALSE
> myor(NA,NA)
[1] NA
> myor(T,NA)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: my mistake in the comment above. As I said at the beginning, this function should return the same as the "or" function |, except for when F|NA.

Comment: then `if ((is.na(a) & !b) | (is.na(b) & !a)) then FALSE else a|b` should work... (or `ifelse((is.na(a) & !b) | (is.na(b) & !a), FALSE, a|b)` for vectors